# Equivalent code of Mage::app()->getLocale()->getNumber() in Magento2

Tags: magento-1.9, magento2, code-migration

I would like to find out the `magento2` equivalent of the below code from `magento 1`

`Mage::app()->getLocale()->getNumber()`

Can anyone assist me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

inject the class in constructor like below :

```
protected $_localeFormat;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\Locale\FormatInterface $localeFormat
) {
    $this->_localeFormat = $localeFormat;
}
```

and then use it like :

```
$value = $this->_localeFormat->getNumber($price);
```

Comment: @MurtuzaZabuawala, https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/68928/chat-between-teja-and-murtuza?tab=general

Answer (score 1):

In magento 2 `getNumber()` available in following class..
you can add that class in construct and use it.

```
Magento\Framework\Locale\Format::getNumber()
```